# Finding the quotient space for a given homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, geometric-topology

Let me introduce some definitions beforehand.

**Definition** Let $X,Y \subset R ^n$ be disjoint sets. Suppose that $X'\subset X$ and $Y' \subset Y$, and $h: X' \rightarrow Y'$ is a homeomorphism. Define a partition $P(h)$ on $X \cup Y$ to be the collection of all pairs $\{ x, h(x)\}$ for $x \in X' $, and all single-element sets $\{z\}$ for $z \ in (X-X')\cup(Y-Y')$. A set $W \subset R^m$ is the result of attaching $X$ and $Y$ via the map $h$, denoted $X \cup _ h Y$, if $W$ is an identification space of $X \cup Y$ and $P(h)$.

Identification spaces are quotient spaces by the way.

Here is the question:
Let $X = [0,2]$ and $Y=[3,5]$, let $X'=[1,2]$ and $Y'=[3,4]$, and let $h:X' \rightarrow Y'$ given by $h(x)=x+2$. Now, we are asked to find the quotient mapping and quotient space.

Here is my attempt:
[image]

Pictorially, we will find a quotient map such that the parts with red arrows will go to the same  place. Geometrically, if we glue these parts together, we will get somewhat conic shape -not exactly, very roughly-. I am open to any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You get a one-dimensional shape, the picture is misleading. Basically you get a single interval as a result I think.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Do you have any suggestions regarding quotient map?

Answer (score 1):

Define a continuous $f:[0,2] \cup [3,5] \to [0,3]$ by

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
          x & 0 \le x \le 2\\
          x - 2 & 3 \le x \le 5\\
\end{cases}$$

Then the induced map by $f$ to the quotient $X \cup_h Y$ (i.e. $\tilde{f}([x]) = f(x)$ for the classes $[x]$ in $X \cup_h Y$) is well-defined,  1-1 and onto and continuous so we have a homeomorphism with $[0,3]$.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is crystal clear now. Both f,f-inverse are continuous as well.

Comment: @user722271 $f^{-1}$ does not exist and homeomorphism of $\tilde{f}$ follows by compactness.

Comment: A'ight. Compactness is preserved under continuity. We have a union of two closed and bounded, thus compact sets, so its image-f is onto- is compact as well... Now, I got it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user722271:  Careful, "closed and bounded iff compact" is a theorem special to subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @user722271 the union of $X$ and $Y$ is compact hence so is $ X \cup_h Y$. And $[0,3]$ is Hausdorff.